# Main water line from 3/4 to 1in, meter and pressure

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure

I come here with a question since the plumber from a company that I called earlier this week gave me conflicting information compared to what I've read online.

I've purchased a house last year and I am looking to do some improvements on the plumbing of the house. I am planning on doing the whole house in PEX A later on this year, which I am confortable doing, but I dont want to mess with anything without making sure my connection to the main line is safe and trust worthy.

Note I am currently in Lyndhurst NJ.

Currently I have the following setup coming from the street:

[image: Current setup coming from the street]

Before I do anything on the house I would like to hire a company to remove that elbow that reduces my 1in pipe to 3/4in right before the meter.

I understand that the meter would need to be changed (looked up the price and it's not too bad).

So now to the part I didn't fully understand from the company, they were saying that if I removed that elbow I would have a higher pressure on the house and that would likely be a problem.

I dont see why I couldn't just have the meter, a ball valve and then a pressure reducer for the rest of the house. My goal isn't to redo the whole house now, it's just so that I have more flow to be able to use the sprinklers and take a shower, or use multiple things at the same time.

Can anyone help me understand a little bit better what this plumber was talking about or if my theory here is correct that there would be no problems.

Here is also a picture of the actual setup:

[image: Picture of the setup]

best regards,

Comment: Before you start working on your plumbing you absolutely must  have a reliable mens of shutting off water to your property especially to the inside. Is the "old style" valve just after the meter reliable and accessible by you? What about the one before the meter?  Why do you want to replace the copper with PEX?

Comment: There is no reason to remove that elbow before the meter. Changing to a 1" meter will increase the flow rate, but a 3/4" has a good flow rate. Is there a reason you want to increase your flow rate? When the irrigation system is delivering water are the inside flow rates too low?

Comment: Oh yeah for sure, I 100% know that, my goal is to make sure I have redone that part 100% so I have control over the whole thing. My goal is to replace the "old style" valves for ball valves so it's more reliable. 

I dont like Copper because of how much harder it is to service it by myself, I know want to learn how to do the soldering pipe, ProPex (Pex A) is so much reliable and easier to do in a DIY fashion. If you have a expanding tool (which I am planning on getting)

Comment: So I am already doing service on the main line why not change the meter to 1in and reduce it after so if I ever want to increase the size later on I dont have to call someone to do it for me, since my goal is to stop the Copper right after the 1in ball valve I want to hire someone to put in this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your picture, the diagram and your description, I'm guessing that you are in an area that has low water pressure. This isn't uncommon. I don't see a PRV (pressure regulating valve) on the main coming in to the house.
In my experience water companies typically provide water at the curb at about 100 to 150 psi. This varies due to many factors such as distance from the water supply, number of taps on the line (new construction, etc.) corrosion buildup in the lines, leaks, etc. and it can change over time. A good pressure range for most homes is 60 to 70 psi. Too much higher can cause damage to appliances and leaks in your domestic water system. This is why a PRV is sometime needed to reduce pressure.
From a practical perspective you can only have as much pressure in your system as what is provided at the curb from your water supplier. You might want to spend $10 on a screw-on pressure meter device at your local hardware store and use it to get a pressure reading from a faucet bibb so you know your current pressure. It's important to make sure all other taps in the system are closed so you get an accurate reading.
I would start there and then contact your water supplier. They should be able to give you a good idea of what pressure should be in your area. If they are saying it's 125 psi and you're reading 40 psi at your bibb - something may be wrong between the curb and your house.
Start with the above to help isolate the problem before you spend a lot of money on new plumbing.

Comment: Note that the pressure will drop when water is flowing out a delivery point. For example suppose a pressure gauge reads 70 psi when your water is off. It might read 40 or 50 psi when you turn on a single high flow tap.

Comment: Yes but if the only tap you open is capped by the meter for the reading you will get an accurate reading at that tap. You do have to make sure that all other taps are closed.

Comment: I just want the OP to realize that the pressure reading is dependent on flow status. Getting a larger meter will not change the pressure reading with no flow, but a larger meter can be expected to keep the pressure under flow closer to the  pressure with no flow. Same with the 90 deg bend.

Comment: I was thinking of getting something like a 1in pressure valve with a Gauge attached to it anyways. Like: https://www.supplyhouse.com/Caleffi-535361HA-1-NPTF-Pressure-Reducing-Valve-w-Gauge-Low-Lead-Pre-adjustable

Answer (score 3):

The size of the water line does not determine the water pressure. Increasing the water line will affect the volume of water flow and the pressure drop in that line. If you increased the incoming line to 2" the pressure would remain the same only the amount of flow available would change. I would check with the water supplier about changing the water meter size. Where I live, the water meter has to comply with the water authority and there is a monthly up-charge for a larger meter.

Since I have never used PEX I can not can't comment on it's use.

Comment: I would also verify that it is acceptable for you to change the meter. In most city’s they own everything to the meter even though they charge you for a meter change in some locations. Increasing the pipe and meter size should help with flow but a single 90 won’t change the pressure as George states. You don’t show the change in size this would also be helpful.

Comment: Yeah over here, I checked the local water company has the prices for the meter, you can buy it from them. Which I am totally fine with, it's about 260 bucks I think for a 1in. Thanks so much for the answer on the Water Pressure thing, I was confused by the plumber, since all I read is that pipe size doesn't change pressure.